# I want to overwrite default error message of ASP.NET Web API - No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller search in that  I have a methods "details" inside the controller - like route - `api/details/id=123&clienId=12444`.

I am getting default ASP.NET error message when we hit details alone
example

> Route api/details - 404 - no HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

I do not have any method that has details without parameters

I need to overwrite the error message in the controller when it is hit saying No matching routes found

I tried to catch the exception I am not able to. I need to return customised message when the routes are matching

Answer (score 0):

> overwrite the error message in the controller when it is hit saying No
> matching routes found

Do you want to redirect to an action method page when there is a 404 error ?

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{       
    await next();    
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
    {
        context.Request.Path = "/Home/CustomError";
        await next();
    }
});
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   
    public IActionResult CustomError()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

CustomError View:

```
No matching routes found
```

Result:

[image]

Besides, you can read [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to know more.